# Мобильная версия сайта

Tags: css3, html, javascript, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте. Хотел задать такой вопрос. У меня есть сайт который прекрасно работает на всех 4-х браузерах (включая `IEv6` :)). Теперь хочу сделать мобильную версию сайта. Скажите, что нужно знать для верстки сайта для мобильных телефонов, какие могут быть "подводные камни". К примеру, я заметил что `OperaMini` не отображает таблицы правильно, а показывает все одной строкой. Хотел бы услышать такие особенности, как `Cookies`, `JavaScript`, минимальное разрешение экрана, `CSS3` и остальные важные отличия от их стандартных версий. В общем все, что нужно учесть при переходе на мини-версию сайта.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Почитать можно [тут](http://www.cameronmoll.com/archives/000577.html) и [тут](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-mobile/). О, чуть не забыл, еще [тут](http://www.xiper.net/learn/bonus-books/programming-the-mobile-web/javascript-mobile/javascript-mobile-compatibility.html) почитайте.**

---

Постараюсь привести некоторые данные, которые отсутствуют в вышеуказанных статьях или высветлены не полностью. Первым делом создаем отдельную каскадную таблицу стилей, которая будет использоваться только для мобильных устройств. Подключать ее нужно подобным образом:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/handheld.css" media="handheld">
```

или(предпочтительнее использовать первый вариант)

```
<style type="text/css">@import "/css/handheld.css" handheld</style>
```

- "/css/handheld.css" - путь к
  таблице стилей для моб. устройств;
- media="handheld" - указание браузеру,
  что данный ресурс следует
  использовать только в случае
  просмотра веб-страницы с помощью
  устройств у которых маленькое
  расширение экрана. Рекомендую еще
  создать CSS файлик для
  принтеров(значение "print" атрибута
  "media"). Можно почитать подробно на
  [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media).

**Как правильно подключать данный стиль.**
Если на странице есть стили для всех устройств (со значением "all" атрибута "media", прошу заметить что оно устанавливается по-умолчанию), то:

- Создаем файл "reset.css". Он должен
  обнулять свойства всех нужных нам
  селекторов.
- После подключение/объявление всех стилей в шапке странице(тег head) подключаем файл "reset.css". При подключении не забываем указать тип устройств, для которых данная каскадная таблица стилей будет отображаться, - "handheld".
- Подключаем стили для мобильных устройств.

Если же все стили на станице четко распределены по типам носителей(устройств, что отображают страницу), то файл "reset.css" подключать не нужно.
Нежданно-негадано проблема может возникнуть из-за так называемых [внутренних стилей](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/sposoby-dobavleniya-stiley-na-stranitsu). Подогнать их под разные девайсы относительно затруднительно(но возможно, к примеру с помощью JS), поэтому рекомендую вынести их в соответствующие файлы стилей.

---

**Рекомендации при верстке под handheld:**

- Не верстайте с помощью WML. Он
  безнадежно устарел и вместо него
  используется XHTML/CSS, по крайней
  мере на момент написания этого
  ответа.
- Из-за того, что свойства float, clip,
  overflow, both не пашут на
  большинстве мобильных телефонов,
  придется ограничиться использованием
  элементов с абсолютным
  позиционированием(position:
  absolute;). Так же избегайте блоков
  fixed. Насчет relative ничего
  написать не могу.
- Сокращенные свойства типа:  "margin:
  10px 20px 30px 40px;" придется
  разбить на более простые:
  "margin-top: 10px; margin-right:
  20px; margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;".
- Табличная верстка крайне
  нежелательна. Она плохо
  обрабатывается устройствами подобного
  вида. Запрещены вложенные таблицы и
  даже не работают атрибуты
  "cellpadding" и "cellspacing".
- Cookie чаще всего адекватно
  устанавливаются и считываются, причем
  в даже в старых телефонах.
- Импортировать внешние шрифты
  запрещено.
- CSS3 юзать рано, его поддержка почти
  отсутствует.
- Flash контент или заменять на
  аналогичный не флеш или прятать.
  Причиной тому является его проблемное
  отображение на моб. устройствах и
  сомнения в дальнейшей поддержке.
- Использовать JS для формирования
  дизайна страницы по-минимуму. Речь
  идет не про динамическую составляющую
  страницы. Постараюсь
  продемонстрировать на примере:
  Некоторый верстальщик создал
  страничку, после тестов увидел, что
  один из блоков не на своем месте.
  Нескольких минут борьбы с CSS
  и верстальщик понимает, что где-то
  стиль проблемного блока
  перекрывается из-за чего все его
  старания решить проблему
  безрезультатны. Вместо того, что бы
  искать проблемное определение ему
  приходит в голову "гениальная" идея
  пофиксить положение блока
  javascript-ом, выполнив его после
  загрузки страницы. На таких костылях
  страничка была добавлена на сайт и
  опубликована. Минутой позже страничку
  просматривает некоторый пользователь
  с использованием ПК. Элементы сайта
  отображаются нормально, пользователь
  счастлив. Еще через минуту с
  мобильного телефона заходит на только
  что опубликованную страницу другой
  пользователь, телефон не самый новый
  и JS у него не пашет, именно поэтому
  проблемный блок коварно меняет свою
  позицию превращая великолепнейший 
  дизайн в кашу. Пример не очень удачный, но суть отображает.